# Best game engine which does not require coding

Tags: game-engine

I want to make 3d games without writing a single line of code. I cannot use unreal engine due to some reason. I would really like a suggestion. I don't know why site's always add unity to the list. Unity requires programming. Please tell.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create great games without a single line of code. There are several engines out there that creates games without code, but you will be only constrained to casual games.

However, Unity has a plugin called Bolt. You might probably want to check it out.

Comment: But this asset is not free. I need a free asset

Comment: Well, I don't think there are any good visual scripting tools for Unity unless you pay for them. Good luck with finding one though.

Comment: So is there any visual scripting engine?